# unable to include circular_buffer in structure

Tags: c++, c++11

i am new to cpp. I wish to put "boost::circular_buffer histpos(5);" with 5 spaces to store 5 elements inside a cpp structure as member.

i try this :

```
typedef struct histposRecorder{
   int32_t track_id;
        boost::circular_buffer<float> histpos(5);

}coRecord;
```

and i get this error :

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
        boost::circular_buffer<float> histpos(5);
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

this is the circular_buffer website i am referring to:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

please show me how to solve it

The reason i want to put it in structure because i will have a lot different copies of circular_buffer to store the velocities of different objects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot initialize a member in its declaration.

Comment: You need to understand the differences between object **declaration**, **definition** and **initialization**.

Comment: [If you use curly braces, you may get what you want.](https://arne-mertz.de/2015/08/new-c-features-default-initializers-for-member-variables/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Members can be initialized in a class/struct definition using a brace (or equals) initializer [since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization):

```cpp
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

struct coRecord {
  int32_t track_id;
  boost::circular_buffer<float> histpos {5};
};
```

Comment: i get this error "Invalid pkt_timebase, passing timestamps as-is." after adding it. any idea?
thanks

Comment: That appears to be a ffmpeg/libavcodec Nvidia CUVID decoder error message. It's unrelated to boost::circular_buffer. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6aeaac3e1c40a7e0691a8accb90adc29c6b4bc23/libavcodec/cuviddec.c#L1039-L1040

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the initialization elsewhere:

```
struct coRecord {
  int32_t track_id;
  boost::circular_buffer< float > buffer;

  coRecord() : buffer(5) {}
};
```

In you class definition you can only *declare* member variables, but not initialize them. Instead by providing such a default constructor, you can still do the needed initialization:

```
coRecord recorder; // automatically reserves 5 places in the buffer
```

Comment: i get this error "Invalid pkt_timebase, passing timestamps as-is." after adding it. any idea?
thanks

Comment: A quick google search hints that this is an error inside ffmpeg or another part of your software, but not of boost.